# Pattern Recognition

Tags: java

So my code is done, but now I need it to print out wether the chosen numbers are equal or not!

I've made a loop for FALSE / NUMBERS ARE EQUAL, but it doesn't work properly.
Hope you can help.
My code looks like this:

```
package patternrecognition;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class PatternRecognition {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {



        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


        int AntalNumre = -1;

        boolean Gyldignummer = false;
        while (Gyldignummer == false) {
            System.out.print("\n\nIndtast antal numre: ");

            String numre = reader.readLine().trim();

            Gyldignummer = validInteger(numre);

            if (Gyldignummer == false) {
                System.out.println("Indtast et gyldigt nummer");
            } else {

                AntalNumre = Integer.parseInt(numre);
            }

        }


        HashMap vaerdier = new HashMap();

        for (int i = 0; i < AntalNumre; i++) { //Studerendes nummer(i+1)

            boolean GyldigNummer2 = false;

            while (GyldigNummer2 == false) {
                System.out.print("\n\nIndtast en vaerdi for nummer " + (i + 1) + ": ");

                String vaerdi = reader.readLine().trim();
                int vaerdien = -1;

                GyldigNummer2 = validInteger(vaerdi);
                if (GyldigNummer2 == false) {
                    System.out.println("Indtast et gyldigt nummer");
                } else {

                    vaerdien = Integer.parseInt(vaerdi);
                }
                vaerdier.put(vaerdi, new Integer(vaerdien));
            }
        }



        TreeMap SorteretNummer = new TreeMap(vaerdier);

        Iterator nr = SorteretNummer.keySet().iterator();

        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n");
        System.out.println("Numre valgt:");
        System.out.println("------------");


        while (nr.hasNext()) {

            String navn = (String) nr.next();


            int numre = ((Integer) SorteretNummer.get(navn)).intValue();

            System.out.println("" + numre);

            if (numre != numre) {
                System.out.println("FALSE");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("ALLE THE NUMBERS ARE EQUAL");
            }

        }
    }

    public static boolean validInteger(String nummer) {
        boolean validInteger = false;


        try {
            Integer.parseInt(nummer);
            validInteger = true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            validInteger = false;
        }
        return validInteger;

    }
}
```

Comment: So what seems to be a problem? http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html Or should I say, Så hvad der synes at være et problem?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear.

As you can see in the botton of the code, just before the "validInteger" I've made "if (numre != numre") { print false} else {all the numbers...}. But it doesn't check all the numbers. It simply prints 1 number, then prints "ALL NUMBERS ARE..." then number 2, then "ALL NUMBERS ARE.." etc. I don't know how to make it check the numbers you can enter.

Comment: "but it doesn't work properly" does not seem clear to me. It would be much easier if you described what exactly goes wrong. Comments in Danish are mildly annoying, as they take place and do not help, but lack of the problem description kills the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `numre != numre` is bound to be `false` unless of course `numre` happens to be changed in another thread (or be `NaN`, but that's a different story).

Perhaps, you may want to compare pairs of numbers? Or, perhaps, you want to have a data structure holding the numbers you've already seen (e.g. `HashSet` or `BitSet`)?

An example: as user enters numbers, save those to a `HashSet<Integer>`. As soon as he's done, add

```
Set<Integer> set = new hashSet<Integer>();

// ...as we're getting numbers from user

   set.add(numre);

// ...

if (set.size() == 1) 
    System.out.println("OMG they're all the same! " + set);
```

Comment: You are damn right, this is my homework :)
But actually we haven't learned about TreeMap, HashMap, BufferedReader og HashSet yet, I've read about that in my book recently and trying it out! Therefore I ask for some help, e.g. the code etc ^^ So I'm not quite sure how to do the HashSet<interger>, could you give an example please? :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem:

```
if (numre != numre) {
    System.out.println("FALSE");
}
else {
    System.out.println("ALLE THE NUMBERS ARE EQUAL");
}
```

Comparing the same variable to itself: will always print "ALLE THE NUMBERS ARE EQUAL".

EDIT:

Remember the previously entered `Integer` and compare to the most recently entered `Integer`. Use `Integer` and initialise the `previousInt` to `null` so you know to avoid comparison on initial loop iteration.
As it is homework I will not post the code and it will be more benefit to you if you code it yourself.

Comment: Yes I've thought of that. But thats the number that's being printet, so I don't know how to compare all the numbers? The number you choose is being put into "numre" and printed. It's not like I got an array to save the numbers and compare them. Any ideas? :)

Comment: @Daniel Well, errr, get *an array to save the numbers and compare them* perhaps? :)

Comment: Create an `ArrayList<Integer>` to store them. If you need to compare each `Integer` to every other `Integer` in the list then you could use nested `for` loops, remembering to not compare the same `Integer`.

Comment: Possible you could give me an example of how you would code it in my code? :)

Comment: @hmjd have pity, use `HashSet` or `BitSet` :) With `HashSet`, it's `if (set.size() == 1) say("OMG they're all the same!");`

Comment: @hmjd added an example to my post. Hope it helps. By the way, isn't it your homework?

Comment: @Daniel, do you need to check if all numbers entered were equal? If so, just remember the previous integer and compare it to the current. No need for any collections.

Comment: Yep thats what I need, to check if all numbers entered are equal :)